# SciKitLearn Estimator choice

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

Good afternoon,

As a humble newbie working on a Machine Learning project, I was trying out the most basic estimator (Linear regression) even though I'm pretty sure I made the wrong choice based on my data.
In my data I have 38 Columns, in which there is a datetime column, two string columns, and my three targets are: two int type columns and a string (single character) type column, while other columns are made of floats.
Using linear regression (after dropping datetime columns, transforming every string type in numerical one) I'm getting a maximal accuracy of 44% (0.44) out of my model after 10000 iterations with for loop.

Here's my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle

#Import xls#
data_18_19 = pd.read_excel(r'c:\Users\unkno\Desktop\xxxxx_x_.xls')
data_19_20 = pd.read_excel(r'c:\Users\unkno\Desktop\yyyyy_y_.xls')

#fusione dfs#
merge_data = [data_18_19, data_19_20]
data = pd.concat(merge_data, sort=False)


#Drop della colonna Div, tutte l1 e orario perché problematico#
data = data.drop(['Div'], 1)
data = data.drop(['Time'], 1)
data = data.drop(['Date'], 1)

#droplist str list comprehension dei nomi delle colonne#
droplist = [str(x) for x in data.iloc[0:0,37:]]
data = data.drop(droplist, 1)

#Cambio di HT, D, AT in 1,0,2 per HTR e FTR#
data['FTR'] = data['FTR'].replace(['H','D','A'], [1,0,2])
data['HTR'] = data['HTR'].replace(['H','D','A'], [1,0,2])

#Trasformazione s in numeri in ordine alfabetico#
dt = {'At':1,'Bo':2,'Br':3,'Ca':4,'Ch':23,'Em':22,'Fr':21,'Fi':5,'Ge':6,'In':7,'Ju':8,'La':9,'Le':10,'Mi':11,'Na':12,'Pa':13,'Ro':14,'Sa':15,'Sas':16,'Sp':17,'To':18,'Ud':19,'Ve':20}
data['HT'] = data['HT'].replace([i for i in dt.keys()], [j for j in dt.values()])
data['AT'] = data['AT'].replace([i for i in dt.keys()], [j for j in dt.values()])

#definizione della colonna target della predizione#
predict = 'FTR'

#Costituzione delle features(X) e dei target(y)#
X = np.array(data.drop([predict],axis=1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

best = 0
for i in range(10000):
    #split dei dati per validazione#
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.1)
    
    #definizione e training del modello da training#
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    #test di precisione#
    acc = model.score(X_test, y_test)
    
    #predizioni#
    predicts = model.predict(X_test)
    hr_predicts = np.around(predicts)
    
    if acc > best:
        best = acc
        with open(r"c:\Users\unkno\Desktop\dump.pickle", "wb") as doc:
            pickle.dump(model, doc)
            
    print("Precisione: ", acc)
```

I was wandering about how to increase accuracy and which estimator to choose for better results?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No data, no answer for others to provide. Very general description of your issue.

Comment: Is there one independent variable? Linear regression will work for that. More? Try multivariate regression or random forest. You can also use K-fold cross validation to test multiple hyperparameters. You could also use a support vector machine and try with that. Random forest regressor will probably give you the biggest bang for you buck though.

Comment: @Chrispresso Do you mean parameters with much relevance for Hyperparameters?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches. However, a few simple steps without changing much that has been done.

1. Check the model performance after scaling the data. If the scale of the predictors are very different, then the model do not converge properly. I assume, the y that you want to predict is also continuous variable. Check if it follows a normal distribution. Else, applying log transform helps to normalize.
2. Secondly, the random_state is not specified in the train_test_split. Is this intentional ? Please check the performance by setting it to a random int value.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scalar = StandardScaler()
X_train = scalar.fit_transform(X_train)
y_train = scalar.fit_transform(y_train)

# only transform the test data , else it leads to data leakage 
X_test = scalar.transform(X_test)
y_train = scalar.transform(y_test)
```